# Rule based sync in Dynamics CRM Connector

Tags: sitecore-client, dynamics-crm-module

I would need to know on the best way to implement a scenario

**Environment :** Sitecore 9.0.2

**Module:** Dynamics CRM COnnector 2.0.1

## Scenario:

If a particular facet property is not null then the value mapping should not be applied while running the pipeline batch `Sync xConnect contacts to Dynamics`. I have noticed all value Mapping have Rule mapping field. Would like to have an implementation example, could not find any in CookBook.

Thanks,
​Sam

Comment: Wrote a custom rule referring to default null mapping rule, and applied on specific value mapping. This solved my objective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrote a custom rule referring to default null mapping rule, and applied on specific value mapping. This solved my objective